Why can I define a std::string instance that is constinit? Isn't constinit forbidden if an object requires dynamic initialization?
The cppreference mentions that if initialization contains a dynamic initialization part, the program is ill-formed when using constinit in C++20.
I just wonder why the following code compiles then:
constinit std::string str = "Hello";

Since the std::string class involves dynamic memory allocation for storing characters, it seems contradictory. Shouldn't this be disallowed due to the dynamic part?
Tried to compile with flags -std=C++20 and the program compiles fine which shouldn't be.

It is accepted by MSVC and gcc (probably due to SSO as mentioned above), but rejected by clang. See demo1. Increasing the size of the string to get passed SSO causes an error on all 3 major compilers. See demo2.

@wohlstad Clang 18 and newer accepts it.

@HolyBlackCat I now see. In any case I updated my comment with a demo using a longer string (more than SSO can handle), which fails on all 3, which strengthen your insight.

Common std::string implementations don't allocate on the heap if the string is short enough (this is called the "short string optimization" or "SSO").
Since the exact amount of characters that can fit into SSO (if any) depends on the implementation, you probably shouldn't rely on it, or should at least research how the big 3 standard libraries handle this.

This answer is complementary to @HolyBlackCat's answer.
As explained there the reason you succeeded to compile:
constinit std::string str = "Hello";

Is due to short string optimization (SSO).
This is demonstrated in these 2 demos:

The line above compiles on all 3 major compilers.
See demo1.
Increasing the size of the string to more than SSO  can handle ("Hello1234567890123456789012345678901234567890" in this case) , causes a compilation error on all 3 compilers
(e.g. gcc issues: error: 'constinit' variable 'str' does not have a constant initializer).
See demo2.

Note that the specific length supported by SSO is implementation dependant.
In the demo above I simply increased the length until I got the failure. The max length for SSO can change in future versions.
